# How to add data to a (heavily) nested collection in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am a noob at Python and MongoDB and would really appreciate your help with my problem.  My collection in MongoDB looks like this:

```
{
 "Segments" : [
                {
                  Devices : [
                              "IP" : "",
                              "Interfaces" : 
                                             [
                                               {
                                                 "Name" :""
                                               }
                                             ],
                             ],
                             "DeviceName" : "",
                             "SegmentName" : ""
                 }
                ]
}
```

I have an object like so:

```
Node Details: {'node:98a': ['Sweden', 'Stockholm', '98a-3470'], 'node:98b': ['Denmark', 'Copenhagen', '98b-3471', '98b-3472']}
```

I need to update the 'Name' within 'Interfaces' part in the collection above, with values from the Node Details dictionary. I have tried using $set, $addToSet, $push etc., but nothing is helping. I have already added the Segment and DeviceName information.

The output should be as follows:

```
{
     "Segments" : [
                    {
                      Devices : [
                                  {
                                   "Interfaces" : 
                                                 [
                                                   {
                                                     "Name" :"98a-3470"
                                                   }
                                                 ],
                                   "DeviceName" : "node:98a",
                                  }
                                  {
                                   "Interfaces" : 
                                                 [
                                                   {
                                                     "Name" :"98b-3471"
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                     "Name" :"98b-3472"
                                                   }
                                                 ],
                                   "DeviceName" : "node:98b",
                                  }
                                 ],                                 
                      "SegmentName" : "segmentA"
                     }
                    ]
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried a lot in the MongoDB shell and also on Google, but to no avail. Thank you all.

Regards,
trupsster

[[ EDITED ]]
Okay, here is what I have got so far after continuing to poke around after posing the question: I used the following query in MongoDB shell:

```
db.test.mycoll.update({'Segments.SegmentName':'segmentA','Segments.Devices.Name':'node:98a'}, {$set: {"Segments.$.Devices.0.Interfaces.Name" : "98b-3470"}})
```

Now this inserted in the correct place as per my 'schema', but when I try to add the second interface, it simply replaces the earlier one. I tried using $push (complained about it not being an array), and $addToSet (showed another error), but none helped. Can you please help me from this point on?

Thanks,
trupsster

[[ Edited again ]]

I found the solution! Here is what I did:
To add an interface to an existing device:

```
db.test.mycoll.update({'Segments.SegmentName':'segmentA','Segments.Devices.Name':'node:98a'}, {$addToSet: {"Segments.$.Devices.0.Interfaces.Name" : "98a-3471"}})
```

Now, to append to the dict with a new 'Name' within the array 'Interfaces':

```
db.test.mycoll.update({'Segments.SegmentName':'segmentA','Segments.Devices.Name':'node:98a'}, {$addToSet: {"Segments.$.Devices.0.Interfaces" : {"Name" : "98a-3472"}}})
```

As you can see, I used $addToSet.

Now, next step was to add the same information (with different values) to 2nd device, which was done like so:

```
db.test.mycoll.update({'Segments.SegmentName':'segmentA','Segments.Devices.Name':'node:98b'}, {$addToSet: {"Segments.$.Devices.1.Interfaces" : {"Name" : "98b-3473"}}})
```

So that was it! I am so chuffed with myself! Thank you all who took time to read my problem. I hope my solution will help someone.

Regards,
trupsster

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what you actually tried.  To access a sub-document inside an array, you need to use dot notation with numeric indices.  So to address the Name field in your example:

```
Segments.Devices.0.Interfaces.0.Name
```

Did you try that?  Does it work?

Comment: Hello drmirror, sorry about that, I thought my problem description was too long hence didn't add tedious, non-working statement that I had tried. Your solution would work, I guess, if Name was an array too, but it isn't, it is dict. I have now found the solution, and hope that it will help someone. Thank you for taking the time out to suggest a possible solution though!